# Python: Filtering and Printing tuples from a list of tuples

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of tuples like this:

```
lst = [(4, hen), (9, duck2), (45, soup), (87, Henry5)....]
```

Now I want only the tuples which don't have any numbers in the first index element of the tuple. So my output from the above code should be like this:

```
matr = [(4, hen),(45, soup)]
```

And I need to save the matr into a xls file. I'm able to achieve this and print it to my console, but when I save the output, I get a few blank rows embedded in between the actual rows. Please help!

Here's my code:

```
    # Code generating some words into the list 'words'
    d = {}
    for w in words:
        if w in d:
            d[w] += 1
        else:
            d[w] = 1

    lst = [(d[w],w) for w in d]
    lst.sort(reverse=True)

    matr = {i for i in lst if not any(c.isdigit() for c in i[1])}

    workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
    sheet = workbook.add_sheet('test')

    sheet.write(0,0,'Index')
    sheet.write(0,1,"Word")
    sheet.write(0,2,"Count")       

    i = 1
    for count, word in matr:
        if count >1:
            print count, word.encode("utf-8")
            sheet.write(i, 0, i)
            sheet.write(i, 1, word)
            sheet.write(i, 2, count)
        i += 1    


    workbook.save(r'Dummy_4.xls')
```

This is my output on console:

```
471 mistborn
2 nap
12 glare
2 diarrhea
14 wiping
```

But my xls output looks something like this:

[Output with blank rows amidst actual rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bV1PV.png)

I'm assuming the blank rows are coming in place of the removed tuples. How to get an output without those blank rows? Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be for lines with `count == 1`

This should fix it:

```
i = 1
for count, word in matr:
    if count >1:
        print count, word.encode("utf-8")
        sheet.write(i, 0, i)
        sheet.write(i, 1, word)
        sheet.write(i, 2, count)
        i += 1
```

Comment: Oh great! Thanks. I completely missed out on that one